# Arel query on the sum of column of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have a model `Bill` that `has_many_charges`.

I'm working on a query that will produce all bills that have charges totaling x amount. I've looked over [Arel's](https://github.com/rails/arel) documentation, but haven't quite figured out the proper way to form this query.

I've tried:

```
bills.join(charges)
.on(bills[:id].eq(charges[:bill_id]))
.where(charges.project(charges[:dollars].sum.lt(100)))
```

However I keep getting syntax errors when I execute this ( calling `to_sql` before executing with ActiveRecord. I'm not familiar with Arel, so am not sure how to reform this. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how this is setup?

If `Bill` `has_many :charges`, and `charges` has a `:bill_id` field, you should be able to call. `Bill.find(id).charges`. If that works, you can call the `where` query on `charges`.

So if you are looking for bills with a price of 100 as in your example.

```
bill = Bill.find(id)
bill.charges.where(dollars: 100)
```

If you want a range, you can supply a range:

```
bill.charges.where(dollars: 90..110)
```

**EDIT** based on comments.

bill.rb

```
def self.select_bills(amount)
  all.select { |bill| bill.sum_of_charges >= amount }
end

def sum_of_charges
  charges.pluck(:dollars).sum  
end
```

call it.

```
Bill.select_bills(100)
```

Comment: Hmmm..I'll clarify. If one bill has N charges, and those N charges total over 100 dollars, I want that Bill to be included in the query. If those N charges are less than 100 dollars, I want the Bill excluded. Make sense?